# XLSX - Generate report - Angular

Tags: angular, xlsx

I am having a problem with the report I want, delivering the JSON as follows:

```
[
  {
    // ...
    "forma_pago_cliente": [
      {
        "metodo": "product 1",
        "total": "12"
      },
      {
        "metodo": "product 2",
        "total": "45"
      }
    ],
    // ...
];
```

The result I get is as follows:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdw74.png)

And my expected result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7L5w.png)

My code is as follows.

```
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json, {
      cellDates: true,
    });

  const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = {
  Sheets: {
    tiquetes_vuelos: worksheet,
  },
  SheetNames: [
    'tiquetes_vuelos',
  ],
};

const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, {
  bookType: 'xlsx',
  type: 'array',
});

this.saveAsExcel(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
```

I am trying to get the expected result but I have not been able to, I have been struggling for more than 2 days with this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to flatten the `forma_pago_cliente` object in order to represent it in excel sheet.
Convert the below object to

```
[
  {
    // ...
    "forma_pago_cliente": [
      {
        "metodo": "product 1",
        "total": "12"
      },
      {
        "metodo": "product 2",
        "total": "45"
      }
    ],
    // ...
];
```

like this,

```
[
  {
    // ...
    "product 1": 12,
    "product 1": 45,
    // ...
];
```